# How to Pass Data From a BroadcastReceiver to an Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on my first Android app, which is a paging device. It will intercept a SMS message from a certain number with a certain content in it, display that and then allow the user to send a pre-defined reply back to that same number. I have gathered up code snippets from numerous sources (including stackoverflow of course) but I haven't yet got it working.

My file structure is as shown here

[image]

The part I am struggling with is SmsBroadcastReceiver and ReceiveAlert, which should display the content of the SMS and has a button to initiate the reply.

SmsBroadcastReceiver.java looks like this:

```
package com.example.alert6;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.alert6.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String smsSender = "";
            String smsBody = "";
            for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                smsSender = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            }

            if (smsSender.equals("+420775367297")) {
                if (smsBody.contains("Test")) {
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, smsBody);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // adding this flag starts the new Activity in a new Task
                    context.startActivity();
                }
            }
    }

}
```

ReceiveAlertActivity.java is this:

```
package com.example.alert6;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ReceiveAlertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int SMS_PERMISSION_CODE = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_alert);
    }

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String taskingalert = intent.getStringExtra(SmsBroadcastReceiver.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView receivedAlert = findViewById(R.id.receivedAlert);
        receivedAlert.setText(taskingalert);

public boolean respond(View view) {
        if (!hasReadSmsPermission()) {
            requestReadAndSendSmsPermission();
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SendResponseActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Runtime permission shenanigans
     */
    private boolean hasReadSmsPermission() {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ReceiveAlertActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ReceiveAlertActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ReceiveAlertActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    private void requestReadAndSendSmsPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ReceiveAlertActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                SMS_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}
```

And the manifest is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.alert6">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Alert6">

        <activity
            android:name=".SendResponseActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ReceiveAlertActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ReceiveAlertActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Android Studio is showing errors in SmsBroadcastReceiver and ReceiveAlertActivity but not giving enough information to resolve them.

In SmsBroadcastReceiver, it tells me it cannot resolve method 'startActivity()'. Something needs to go in the brackets, but what?

In ReceiveAlertActivity the problems revolve around receivedalert and taskingalert. It cannot resolve setText because taskingalert is an unknown class. Obviously it's not a class, it's a string so I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Sorting out these problems may not be the end. At the moment I can't test if the app works because the build fails due to the above. Then if I get this lot working, I have some other challenges, like waking up the screen and playing a sound the broadcast receiver is triggered, and stopping the sound when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Observable` object in your `BroadcastReceiver` to store the piece of information you want to send and implement the `Observer` interface in your `Activity` so that it will be warned of every change occuring to the `Observable` object.

Comment: Something else new to read up on! I'll give it a go tomorrow, though I was hoping to do it with Intents and thought I was fairly close to making it work.